# Confused with referencing an interface from a c# tutorial

Tags: c#

I'm following a c# tutorial on udemy and finding how the code works very confusing. I'll paste the code then explain why

```
   public interface ILogger
{
    void LogError(string message);
    void LogInfo(string message);
}

 public class DbMigrator
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public DbMigrator(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Migrate()
    {
        _logger.LogInfo("Migrationg started at {0}" + DateTime.Now);

        // Details of migrating the database

        _logger.LogInfo("Migrationg finished at {0}" + DateTime.Now);
    }
}

 public class FileLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly string _path;

    public FileLogger(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }

    public void LogError(string message)
    {
        Log(message, "ERROR");
    }

    public void LogInfo(string message)
    {
        Log(message, "INFO");
    }

    private void Log(string message, string messageType)
    {
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(_path, true))
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine(messageType + ": " + message);
        }
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(new FileLogger("C:\\Projects\\log.txt"));
        dbMigrator.Migrate();
    }
}
```

I'm getting confused about how do interfaces work in memory(which I think is called the heap)

since dbmigrator calls migrate()

which is using type of  Ilogger when an instance of FileLogger is passed but appears to work without explicitly casting which I'm finding very confusing to how it works.

Hopefully my question makes sense as a lot of these concepts are new to me and I'm struggling with the correct terminology to explain my confusion

Thanks

Comment: The class implements the interface `ILogger`, why it would be needed a cast? Think about interfaces like a parent class, it's like if you have any class (which all inherit from object) and you should had to cast it to `object` to pass it to a function accepting `object`...

Maybe you need to revise inheritance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance

Comment: migrate() doesn't take a parameter of ILogger. It. It takes a parameter of a type that has the ILogger interface. An interface says what members a class must have and no more memory is used then if a class is defined with the same members but didn't explicitly implement the interface.

Comment: Not really a question for SO... Also, since you're using Udemy, why didn't you ask that question to instructor? You've paid the course, you have every right to ask for explanations...

Comment: Thanks for the responses:
@Gusman This is what I didn't understand and couldn't find an explanation anywhere. As I understand the basics around inheritance when it comes to classes but I didn't understand how it works the same with interfaces as interfaces arent classes. So from what you're saying they work the same in terms of inheritence  and allowing different types to be used in methods and in this example since FileLogger in a way is being upcast to Ilogger if that makes sense?

Comment: @ScottMacMaster so you're saying that it isn't using a type of Ilogger but any type that implements the interface, this is what is confusing me. How is it working in memory. I understand how up and down casting works for classes but I can't wrap my head around how this is working with an interface that could be on any other class. Maybe its simpler then I think and it just hasn't clicked for me yet.

Comment: @Caldazar There usually isn't a response from the developer of the course anymore even though it is a good course, and usually find stack overflow has much better responses. Apologise for not explaining my question very well, I'm struggling to explain what I'm confused with

Comment: @adam Yeah, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

`DbMigrator` can call any class that implements the `ILogger` interface.  It just happens you have a `FileLogger`, but you could also implement a logger that writes to a database, as long as you implement all the functions in the interface.

```
class MySuperLogger : ILogger
{
    void LogError(string message) { /* do something super */ }
    void LogInfo(string message) { /* do something super */ }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(new MySuperLogger());
        dbMigrator.Migrate();
    }
}
```

See how there is no difference in the dbMigrator code, just a different type of `ILogger` was created.  Everything else is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I get that it works  but not exactly why it  works in the sense of I don't understand how passing any class that implements the Ilogger interface can then be in a way converted to type of Ilogger, is it in a way similar to upcasting with classes and it in a way inherits the interface?

Im basically trying to figure out what is happening in memory

Comment: I think you are trying to understand things in too deep a way.  If you don't quite get interfaces, then talking about vtables and function pointers are just going to go over your head.  If you are wanting to know about implementation details (like how vtables are laid out), then you should look at the c# EMCA standard.

Comment: Its how my brain works I need to understand the why and how something is working for it to click for me, I will read through this EMCA standard and hopefully Ill be able to make sense of how it works then

Thanks Neil